# When to use inject vs injectActorRef in Scaldi?

Tags: scala, akka, scaldi

Using Scaldi I want to inject Actors into other Actors. When should I use `inject` vs `injectActorRef`?

For example, in the `Module` I have a binding that looks like this: `binding toProvider new SomeActor()`. When injecting `SomeActor` which method should I use?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?  The documentation is mystifying.

Comment: I don't recall what I landed up doing. It has been a while since I worked on this project.